# Is it good to assign each merchant a database for an online inventory system?

Tags: php, mysql

For example, Company Abc will have it's own database: Database_Abc.

Let's say each Database will consist of the following tables:

1. staffs
2. products
3. inventory
4. logs

or

one centralized database with unique merchant id would be better?

1. staffs - merchant_id
2. products - merchant_id
3. inventory - merchant_id
4. logs - merchant_id

which method is good for scalability?

Comment: You need to do some research on multi-tenancy architecture. There you'll have enough options. As it stands your question is both broad and opinion based. There are so many ways to go about it.

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi thanks a lot for that term!, reading about multi-tenancy architecture now.

Comment: It is not opinion-based. You have objective reason to depart from the obvious and simple answer of a centralized database and have a database per client. Ask the question why the OP may think of increasing the maintenance of many order of magnitude : security, data access restrictions, data distributed on client servers,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not just a question about database management but also a server-side applications thoughts.

1. Starting from a scratch one centralized DB with uniform server-side application will do the trick nicely and in case of horizontal increase of data will scale almost perfectly
2. If you have various and very different requests per each company you'll need to think about implementation for each company with it's own design. Such approach consumes more resources but will fit individual customers

Speaking of database management you'll need to ask yourself following questions

1. What type of data will be stored? You should keep in mind that storing financial data best fits for DECIMAL type for example.
2. Think about relations between tables - thus think about correct FOREIGN KEYs for example.
3. Think about possible shortcomings of MySQL itself - for example, it's not suited well for full-text search
4. How your data will increase in size? If it will increase very rapidly, you will need to think about PARTITIONING for example
5. Think about replication and backup issues.
6. Where will you host your database? You can think about cloud services thus not thinking about administration
   etc.

Comment: thanks @Anton, centralized database makes sense and as you mentioned will be a better option for a stable saas application.

Answer (score 0):

I reccomand you to centralize the database with unique merchant id because is more efficiently for you and for computer (mysql, php, etc.) to manage the database.

Comment: thank you! i have decided to go the centralized way